# make tomcat take project from workspace

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I am working on ubuntu 14.04, have downloaded tomcat7 and then eclipse luna.

I added Tomcat7 to eclipse and started the server. I have changed the port to 3030. When i hit the lolachost:3030, I get a blank page whereas when i deploy a project on server this is the log i see.

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/first
```

This is not my workspace path, and it shows 404 page on browser. i need to configure tomcat7 to point my workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to Add project to Tomcat Server in Eclipse ?

View "Servers" -> your tomcat server -> "Add and Remove"

Comment: Yes i have added the project, still i get 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I think simply running from localhost cannot run your project, first From eclipse run on server, get the url run it on any browser.

Comment: I tried `http://localhost:3030/first/` where first is my project name, I get a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, right click on project run as --> on server and then browser opens with this url.

Comment: So,  it means nothing wrong in tomcat server, the problem may be in ur .jsp files, try run manually like this, `http://localhost:3030/first/yourfile.jsp`